# How do I add image tap code to go to a new screen?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have 2 content views.   One contains a hstack with a set of images.    I  want to click on an image to present the other screen.   So an image and text about science when tapped goes to a description about science.

Could anyone help give me direction?    I’ve got it to present text in the console but I’m really struggling to even grasp the basics.

```
Image(subject.imageName)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 75)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("Tapped")
                }
```

Comment: You already have 2 views, now you need to setup the navigation between them. I think this is covered well in [Apple's SwiftUI Tutorial, Section 6](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation#set-up-navigation-between-list-and-detail),

Answer (score 1):

Just put your image into NavigationLink, like below

```
NavigationView {
        NavigationLink(destination: _YOUR_DESTINATION_VIEW_HERE_) {
            Image(subject.imageName)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 75)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        }
    }
}
```